# 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied when using PDFJS with MS Word Add-in project

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, javascript

Recently, we've tried to add a library [PDFJS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to our Microsoft Office Add-in. There are files included pdf.js and pdf.worker.js into `Scripts/PDFjs` folder.

```
// Home.html
...
<script src="Scripts/PDFjs/pdf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

---

```
// Home.js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
         pdfjsLib.workerSrc = './pdf.worker.js';
    });
}
```

Visual Studio shows an exception and hangs:

> SCRIPT5: Exception was thrown at line 2058, column 5 in
>   https://localhost:44332/Scripts/PDFjs/pdf.js 0x80070005 - JavaScript
>   runtime error: Access is denied. pdf.js (2058,5)

[image: img_1]

Also, worth to mention, when including `pdf.worker.js` from CDN(not locally), like `src="https://npmcdn.com/pdfjs-dist@2.0.943/build/pdf.worker.js"` then it **works like a charm**.

What could this be and how to make it work?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A Visual Studio showed this exception even it is in try/catch block because it's loaded from local machine because it hangs on any local stored file's exception by default, but not remote. So, unchecking a checkbox "**Break when this exception type if thrown**" solved an issue.

> **Roel van**:
>   The reason you didn't get it with CDN is because VS only breaks on
>   exceptions in your own code. It now is considering the lib "your own
>   code" because it's local.

[Prove](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45396215#45396215)